# How to wrevent Table cell to wrap contents in IE8?

Tags: html, html-table

I'm trying to create a tabular view in HTML. If the table is too wide, the overflowing content should hide, but the widths of the cells should not be auto-compressed. Some cells contain more than one item, like the div with class 'btn' in the example.

The following code works in Chrome, but in IE 8 the cell with the div gets wrapped to two lines.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    #container {
      width: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: aqua;
    }
    
    .btn {
      width: 18px;
      height: 18px;
      background-color: red;
    }
    
    .tbl td {
      white-space: nowrap;
    }
    
    .tbl input {
      float: left;
    }
    
    .tbl div {
      float: left;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id='container'>
    <table class='tbl'>
      <tr>
        <td>Item Name</td>
        <td><input style='width:100px' /></td>
        <td>Barcode</td>
        <td class='td2'><input style='width:80px' />
        </td>
        <td>Item code</td>
        <td><input style='width:50px' /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Units</td>
        <td><input style='width:100px' /></td>
        <td>Item type</td>
        <td class='td2'><input style='width:80px' />
          <div class='btn'></div>
          <!-- this is causing a wrap to 2 lines -->
        </td>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td><input style='width:50px' /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```

Screenshot in Chrome:

[image]

Screenshot in IE8:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A `DIV` is a block element, meaning it is not an inline element. The CSS you are using prevents word-wrapping, but a `DIV` is not a word so this will not apply. The easy solution is to use the inline equivalent of a `DIV`: a `SPAN`.

Comment: Unfortunately, replacing the DIV of the red block to SPAN does not solve the problem, the behavior is the same.

Comment: .td2 { min-width:100px } should fix this.